# Trying to connect to database in Java DB netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I'm trying to connect to embedded database Java DB from NetBeans 7.1.

this is what I tried:

```
    try{
    String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
    String url = "jdbc:derby:market; create=true";
    String db = "/artikli";
    String user = "wolf";
    String pass = "wolf";
    String query = "SELECT * FROM artikli";
    Connection conn = null;

        Class.forName(driver);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url + db, user, pass);
        java.sql.Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery(query); 

        System.out.println(res.getString("naziv")); // naziv = column name


        res.close();

    }catch(Exception e){

    }
```

My question is how to get data and print, or populate JTable with it, and is this connection good, thanks?
thank you in advance.

Comment: Please post the error you got.

Comment: *I'm trying to connect to embedded database Java DB from NetBeans 7.1* -- I'm not familiar with Netbeans, but try looking in the menus. Perhaps you have a menu like *"Databases"* where you can select *"Connect..."*. HTH.

Comment: I don't have error, just I don't get anything printed. I have already populated database table. My question is how to get data and print, or populate JTable with it, and is this connection good, thanks?

Comment: @Wolf87 - You do have an error, but your `catch` clause is swallowing it. As Oleg suggested, print the exception so you can see it...

Answer (score 1):

You must advance the result set to the first entry, like this:

```
while(res.next()){System.out.println(res.getString("naziv"));}
```

Comment: Complementing: more info about JDBC in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

look at your code, you even don't print expected errors, your catch block is empty, so print this exception and you will get the answer.